# bytes32[] returns true value in remix but when i run it through web3 it returns empty Array why?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs

Note All other functions working perfectly

```
function viewAssets()public view returns(bytes32[] memory){
    return (profile[msg.sender].noOfLand);
}

//profile is a mapping on address=> bytes32[]
//it returns actual values in remix but through web3 it returns an empty array
```

I have tried all three statements but nothing works

```
AbiAnddeployedinstance.method.viewAssets().call();

AbiAnddeployedinstance.method.viewAssets.call();

AbiAnddeployedinstance.method.viewAssets();
```

Comment: Most likely `msg.sender` is a different address when using`web3.js`. You can set `from` address for calls and transactions.

Comment: thanks  it works i mistakenly forgot to include from property in transaction i think i  used the msg.sender in the contract function maybe thats why i should use from